# Embedding LuaJIT - creating include folder

Tags: c++, lua, luajit

I have no problems with LuaJIT, it great and easy to switch from good old Lua.
But for now i use folder `src` from LuaJIT distribution as include for lib.
It is kinda messy because there are `makefile`, `batch scripts`, `c files`, `dasc files`, `src/jit folder` with scripts which i know used with `luajit.exe` e.t.c.
I want to create clean `include` folder with only `h` files (and other if needed) for using  LuaJIT in c++ windows application as shared lib, but quite don't know what to exclude.

My current exclude list

- host folder
- jit folder
- c files
- dasc files
- c files
- luajit.lib - goes to lib folder
- luajit.exp
- luajit.exe
- luajit.dll - goes to bin folder
- makefile
- makefile.dep
- bat files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://luajit.org/install.html

> It's strongly suggested to build LuaJIT separately using the supplied build system. Please do not attempt to integrate the individual source files into your build tree. You'll most likely get the internal build dependencies wrong or mess up the compiler flags. Treat LuaJIT like any other external library and link your application with either the dynamic or static library, depending on your needs.

Build as usual and then copy into your project the files:

- `lua.h`, `lauxlib.h`, `lualib.h`, `luajit.h`, `luaconf.h`;
- `libluajit-5.1.a`, or `luajit-5.1.dll`, or `libluajit-5.1.x.x.x.dylib` or whatever your platform static/shared library file looks like;
- #include headers in project sources and link executables to the library file;

Answer (score 3):

LuaJIT is ABI compatible with Lua, so the regular Lua headers will also work with LuaJIT. The only headers you need are `lua.h`, `luaconf.h`, `lauxlib.h`, and `lualib.h`. LuaJIT also comes with `luajit.h`, but it's not required, and doesn't contain anything that isn't accessible via the `jit` library.